# CSS grid with sticky left column will be scrolled if grid's width is greater than 100% of it's parent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with sticky left and right columns like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 200px);
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-right {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sticky-left">Sticky Left</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="sticky-right">Sticky right</div>
</div>
```

The right column works as expected: always display at the right side.

However the behavior of left column is strange: it will be scrolled to left after about 50% of the grid width, which is not the expected result. What should I do if I want the left column stick to the left side instead of being scrolled?

Comment: it think its a scroll behavior try changing .sticky-left to fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.grid` element is not stretching the `body` width. The `body` width default is set as `display:block` and is getting the width of your viewport (eg: 645px), then when you scroll the page horizontally the sticky property 'loses' because you scrolled more then the `body` width.

One solution would be setting your `body` as `inline-block`, then its width will follow its content width.

```
body {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can just set a width of your `.grid` element

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 200px);
  width: 2000px;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 200px);
}

.grid > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.sticky-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-right {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="sticky-left">Sticky Left</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="sticky-right">Sticky right</div>
</div>
```